# How to extract standard error from coefficients in stan_glm

Tags: r, glm, stan

I have a model that looks like this:

```
fit <- stan_glm(switch ~ arsenic + dist100, 
                family=binomial(link="logit"), 
                data=wells, 
                refresh=0)
```

with an output that looks like this:

```
stan_glm
 family:       binomial [logit]
 formula:      switch ~ arsenic + dist100
 observations: 3020
 predictors:   3
------
            Median  MAD_SD 
(Intercept)  0.0054  0.0810
arsenic      0.4618  0.0415
dist100     -0.9025  0.1040

------
```

and I want the MAD_SD coefficients from the resulting fit. I usually use se(fit) and that gives me the coefficients, but for some reason I get the error

```
Error in se(fit) : argument "predicted" is missing, with no default
```

How do I remedy this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anybody wants to know the answer to this question, stan_glm objects are basically like big tibbles that map a name to an element. In this case, the element is named "ses" and it's a list. So you can do

```
fit$ses[0]
```

to index into it

EDIT: Turns out, the reason that I needed to do this at all was because I imported a package AFTER stan_glm that also has a function called "se" and it got masked.

Comment: Why use stan_glm and not glm?

Comment: not entirely sure, this was for a class. What's the difference between glm and stan_glm?

Comment: Oh I looked at documentation and the stan version is for Bayesian stats

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use `broom.mixed::tidy()`.

```r
library(rstanarm)
library(broom.mixed)
fit <- stan_glm(am ~ mpg + disp, family = binomial, data =mtcars)
tidy(fit)
```

```
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  term        estimate std.error
  <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>
1 (Intercept) -2.57      4.25   
2 mpg          0.188     0.153  
3 disp        -0.00817   0.00698
```